# How can I append a long text to a specific line in bash?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, append, substitution

I have a bash script that copy and paste a txt file (T1,T2..T100) for a hundred times. I need to append to this text file a specific line of code at the 454th line of the txt file.

I tried to use sed and awk but they don't seem to work just fine.

I was trying to do something like this but it didn't work:

```
awk 'NR==454{print "try:
  Mesh_1.ExportMED( r'/home/students/gbroilo/Desktop/Script/Mesh_1.med', 0, SMESH.MED_V2_2, 1, None ,1)
  pass
except:
  print 'ExportToMEDX() failed. Invalid file name?'"}1'
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, it is good that you showed your efforts with code in your question, keep it up. Could you please also mention sample input and expected sample output in your post and let us know then to get a clear picture of question.

Comment: Whenever I tried to run the code I get an error of: syntax error near unexpected token '('. - my output should be a text file that at line 454 adds this part that I want to add with awk. It should be added on the same file and not create a new one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like your formatting of code is NOT correct which is causing syntax issues. For safer side I used `\047` for `'` in code and `\n` for new line which you need in your output.

```
awk 'NR==454{print "try:\n Mesh_1.ExportMED( r\047/home/students/gbroilo/Desktop/Script/Mesh_1.med\047, 0, SMESH.MED_V2_2, 1, None ,1)\n pass\nexcept:\n print \047ExportToMEDX() failed. Invalid file name?\047"}1' Input_file
```

OR in a non-one liner form of above code:

```
awk 'NR==454{print "try:\n Mesh_1.ExportMED( r\047/home/students/gbroilo/Desktop/Script/Mesh_1.med\047,\
0, SMESH.MED_V2_2, 1, None ,1)\n pass\nexcept:\n print \047ExportToMEDX() failed. \
Invalid file name?\047"}1'  Input_file
```

Where `\` is for letting terminal know that code is continuing without any new line in above code.

Comment: This works! but instead of adding this to the existing text file, it prints everything (with the part added with awk) to the terminal leaving the text files empty, should I add >> Input_file at the end of your code?

Comment: @GianmarcoBroilo, in case you want to save output into Input_file itself and If you are using `gawk` newer version then in spite of awk you could use `gawk -i inplace ` in my above code and lemme know how it goes then?

Comment: Now it works! I have just a problem, I defined a counter called path in place of /home/students/gbroilo/Desktop/Script as I want to change this directories for each file I put ${path} but when I add it with gawk it just prints ${path} instead of the content of path. Should I add double quotations?

Comment: Hello! I tried to use the same command to add the text: execfile(r"/home/students/gbroilo/Desktop/Script/Template_6_1/prova.py")                But now I get syntax error and I do not know why :(

Comment: @GianmarcoBroilo, please change " to \" in your above while writing it in code.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i '454a\line one with a quote '\''\n'\''another'\''\nlast line' fileT*
```

Another way:

```
cat <<\!>fileInsert
line one with a quote '
'another'
last line
!
sed -i '454r fileInsert' fileT*
```

Yet another:

```
cat <<\! | sed -i '454r /dev/stdin' fileT*
line one with a quote '
'another'
last line
!
```

If you want to insert specific text to specific files use GNU parallel, as so:

```
parallel -q sed -i '/454r fileInsert{}' fileT{} ::: {1..100}
```